# Check if directory mounted with .NET

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I want to write code when I check if a directory is already mounted or not (and do something according to the answer).

I saw some solutions in bash which use something like :

`if mount | grep /mnt/md0 > /dev/null; then
    % Do something`

Is there a way to do the same procedure in .NET?
Or alternatively, a away to check if a server is register on the fstab for mounting ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "mounted"? This has no meaning in .NET or Windows. It would have meaning only if you used .NET Core on Linux

Comment: In both OSs though you can check if a directory exists with `Directory.Exists`. Checking for servers and mounted network drives or network shares is OS-specific

Comment: Yes of course , I'm using it on Linux OS. I do not want to know if a directory exist in local place. I want to check if a remote directory is mounted.

Comment: Do you want to know about the servers? Or just whether the folder exists? What do you want to do once you find out whether the folder exists or not? I suspect your actual question is something different, and the answer depends on what you actually want to do. Why ask about mounts when you can use `Directory.Exists` ? Explain what you want in the question itself, and use the appropriate tags.

Comment: That way you can only check if a local mountpoint is mounted to something or not. You still don't know what has been mounted. I think you'd have to check the fstab (?)

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395721/check-all-mount-point-are-mounted-according-to-fstab-file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know the Directory is exists. I want to know if it is mounted or not. I have code that do mount and unmount to some folders , so I want to test it and find out if the mounting succeeded or not . the code is written on Windows but will run on Linux so I can't manually check (therefore want to check it by code).

Comment: @shaniklein are you *sure* that `Directory.Exists` will return `true` if the directory isn't mounted? I doubt that. As for `code is written on Window` different OSs and file file systems have different ways of handling network shares. Adding a share as a network drive on Windows isn't the same as mounting an NFS share on Linux. What does the Windows code look like? What does it mount?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe it will helps. But If I do mount to a folder, than unmount - will the `Directory.Exists` will return `true` or `false`?

Comment: @shaniklein explain what you want to do in the question itself and post all relevant information. Don't force people to guess or try to pull the info out in the comments. As for maybes, **try it out**. Windows 10 has a Linux subsystem.

Comment: @shaniklein this means, even if you haven't installed WSL yet, if you post your code  in the question others will be able to take it and test it on their Windows 10 machines.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I believe that you can check if the directory exists and take action depending on the result, however in order to answer your question, you can try to use the `DriveInfo` class to get all the Drives mounted in the computer and compare the names:

In the example and getting just the network mapped drives

```
string myDrive = "D";
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    if (d.IsReady == true && d.DriveType == DriveType.Network && d.Name == myDrive)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Original Code [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like there:

```
using System.IO;

// and actually checking the directory for the existence
if (Directory.Exists(path))
  //Do something
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it takes about 30 seconds for the Directory.Exists to return a result if the mount is not there.